# Redis continuously takes a large amount of memory and grows until killed by OOM

Tags: redis, node-redis

Currently, my 8GB RAM server is using up 5.33GB for Redis (Other parts of the server take up about 1.6GB, so even immediately after rebooting the server, I'm already at ~7GB RAM [88%]). Redis's memory usage continues to grow until it is eventually killed by Ubuntu's OOM, causing a flurry of errors for my node application.

I've attached the Redis INFO output at the bottom of this post. I had originally thought there might be too many keys in redis, but I read from Redis (http://redis.io/topics/faq) that 1 million keys is ~ 100MB. We have about 2 million (~200MB - nowhere near 5GB), so this couldn't possibly be the issue.

My questions are: 
 - Where is redis consuming all of this memory? The keyspace doesn't take up much at all.
 - What can I do to stop it from continuously consuming more memory?

Thanks!

```
# Server
redis_version:2.8.6
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:f73a208b84b18824
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 3.2.0-55-virtual x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.6.3
process_id:1286
run_id:6d3daee5341a549dfaca63706c40c44086198317
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:1390
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
lru_clock:771223
config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf

# Clients
connected_clients:198
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:72

# Memory
used_memory:5720230408
used_memory_human:5.33G
used_memory_rss:5826732032
used_memory_peak:5732485800
used_memory_peak_human:5.34G
used_memory_lua:33792
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.02
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.5.0

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:94
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1412804004
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:40
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok

# Stats
total_connections_received:382
total_commands_processed:36936
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:2421
keyspace_misses:1
pubsub_channels:1
pubsub_patterns:9
latest_fork_usec:1361869

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:15.95
used_cpu_user:101.34
used_cpu_sys_children:12.55
used_cpu_user_children:146.17

# Keyspace
db0:keys=2082234,expires=1162351,avg_ttl=306635722644
```

Comment: Avoid oom killer by setting maxmemory. What's in your keys? The number of keys is certainly a factor but also the size of their values (and the lengths of their names)/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response Itamar. I was under the false (and really didn't think enough) impression that the keys and values would all roughly be the same size. Turns out there were some hashes stored from kue that were over 10KB each, and we had hundreds of thousands of them. Removing those guys worked.

Thanks again.